# Laravel migrations break when using database Connection Pool

Tags: laravel, postgresql, digital-ocean, connection-pooling

I have a laravel application connected to a database via a Digital Ocean Connection pool. 
It is a postgreSQL database with the following config

```
'pgsql' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'sslmode' => 'require',
            'schema' => 'public',
            'options' => array(
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
            ),
        ],
```

Whether I use a DATABASE_URL or the other paramaters does not make a difference. 
I get the following error when running `php artisan migrate:status` but all migrate commands fail.
`Error: Migration table not found` 
If I instead connect to the database directly (using the same DB user) this command and others instead work correctly.

I have tried adding the `'scheme' => 'public'` line into my config which seemed to fix similar issues for other's. I have also tried changing the Pool Mode in Digital Ocean to both session and statement. 

**Edit:** It turns out the laravel runs this command to check if the migrations table exists 
`select * from information_schema.tables where table_catalog = '{poolName}' and table_schema = 'public' and table_name = 'migrations' and table_type = 'BASE TABLE'` 
where {poolName} is the name of the pool in Digital Ocean (and the value of DB_DATABASE). This causes the issue as the table_catalog is different to the pool name. 

To fix this I followed the steps to resolve from this issue https://github.com/laravel/framework/discussions/43536